# How can I know which button is pressed (back or forward)?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am developing a Google Chrome extension, and I want to listen for back and forward button click events separately.
For example, just printing to console 'back button pressed' if back is pressed and the same for the forward button.

Could you please help me, and explain how can I achieve this result?

Comment: you should share some example code for how you are approaching or planning to so people can advice accordingly. Else its a very broad question.

Comment: Hm. There is a [`webNavigation` API that catches forward/back](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#event-onHistoryStateUpdated) but I can't readily see how to discriminate between those events.